# How to detect whether my code is executed as a Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, dynamic-import, webpack-bundle

I'm currently experimenting with the following strategy to dynamically load a json file from a path relative to my module :

- If my code is bundled as a Webpack bundle, use `import(filename.json)`
- In any other case, fall back to an AJAX call, with an absolute path

The following seems to work fine :

```
function parse (fileName, callback) {
  var path = "./relative/path/to/" + fileName + ".json";
  var cb = process.bind(this, fileName, callback);
  if (typeof webpackJsonp !== "undefined") { // <-- Test if run as Webpack bundle
    // Do dynamic import
  } else {
    // Do Ajax call
  }
}
```

However, I can't find any documentation on `webpackJsonp`, however, so I assume this is not part of Webpack's public API.

I also noticed that `webpackJsonp` is a function in 3.12 and an `Object` (inheriting from `Array`) in 4.28, indicating how fragile it is to rely on the presence, value or type of `webpackJsonp`.

Is there a (future-proof) reliable way test whether my code is being run as a Webpack bundle, using public API?

Basically, what should I replace `typeof webpackJsonp !== "undefined"` with, to achieve the same effect, but using public API?

Additionally, I'm also having some problems with getting the actual import to work in Webpack 4.28. See [import() breaks in Angular 7.2.3 + Webpack 4.28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651712/import-breaks-in-angular-7-2-3-webpack-4-28) for that.

Comment: what about if `__webpack_hash__` exists?

Comment: @PlayMa256¨: `Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_hash__ is not defined`